# Researching extraposition in a syntactic treebank

Tags: syntax, english, corpora, syntax-trees, phrase-structure

I'm writing a paper on extraposition in English (and other right-branching discontinuities). I have found a lot of interesting theory on this but the instructions say that if possible concrete corpus research is to be conducted. I've had some experiences with corpora before, but they aren't really good for analysing syntactic phenomena in my experience. I did some research online and discovered that Treebanks could perhaps help me. Do any of you know any good syntactic treebanks and search tools I could use?

Comment: Start with a pseudocode description of what **you** mean by "extraposition". Does it always need _it_? Is extraposition from NP included? Is right-dislocation included? Etc. Then you'll hafta learn the treebank coding system and see how your parses work out in practice. This is how one learns the diff between theory and practice.

Comment: Extraposition is a displacement phenomenon. Treebankers are terrible at dealing with this stuff, because the annotation methods they use often don't cover the linguistically more challenging areas. My suggestion is to go back to the theoretical work you've already discovered, and look at the grammatical and ungrammatical examples that are used in the discussion.